# Spring 3, Flex 4 Integration with SpringFlex 1.5.0.M2 api + configuration

Tags: flex4, blazeds, spring-3

We are working on a project where we are using Spring 3 to create a web platform and using Flex 4 to create a specific client side application. Currently, we need to integrate Spring project with Flex.

We are using Spring-Flex integration library version: 1.5.0.M2

I checked the older questions but the integration configurations defined at those entries are generally for previous versions of BlazeDS and Spring. And as I understad, there may be some differencies.

Can anybody tell me how to do the configuration in web.xml and any other xml files needed,and how the folder structures will be. Any up-to-date tutorial links will be appreciated.

Our business requirements are:

Two servlets should exist: 1) projectServlet that has mappings /*.html
                           2) flexServlet    that has mappings /messageBroker/*

Our service classes that can be used in Flex side will be like:

```
package com.ecognitio.service;

import org.springframework.flex.remoting.RemotingDestination;
import org.springframework.flex.remoting.RemotingInclude;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
@RemotingDestination
public class Foo {

    @RemotingInclude
    public void sayHello(String name){
        System.out.println("Hello: "+name);
    }

}
```

Regards,

Ugur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [Flex 4, Hibernate 3, and Spring 3 Integration Refcard](http://www.jamesward.com/2010/06/14/flex-4-hibernate-3-and-spring-3-integration/) walks through the process of setting everything up and should work fine with 1.5.0.M2 (assuming you have changed the namespace in the Spring config file).  But here is a basic web.xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns
/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
  version="2.4">

  <display-name>Project Template</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</liste
ner-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

That should be enough to get you started.